# How to use jQuery Draggable an advanced approach

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui-draggable

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/HyB52/)**

I have this jquery fiddle what i want is the `cover` to be draggable inside `pic-area` but only till its completely filled leaving no white region. Take a look please.

```
#pic-area{
    overflow:hidden;
    height:150px;
    width:500px;
    border:2px solid #000;

}
```

***UPDATE***

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#cover").draggable({

    stop: function(ev, ui) {
        var hel = ui.helper, pos = ui.position;
        //horizontal
        var h = -(hel.outerHeight() - $(hel).parent().outerHeight());
        if (pos.top >= 0) {
            hel.css({ top: 0 });
        } else if (pos.top <= h) {
            hel.css({ top: h });
        }
        // vertical
        var v = -(hel.outerWidth() - $(hel).parent().outerWidth());
        if (pos.left >= 0) {
            hel.css({ left: 0 });
        } else if (pos.left <= v) {
            hel.css({ left: v });
        }
    }
 });

});
```

Here i have solved it ! **[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/e93Z5/6/)**

**UPDATE2**

[ALTERNATIVE](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/HyB52/1/)

```
var topX = $('#pic-area').outerWidth() - $('#cover').width() + ($('#pic-area').offset().left*2);
var topY = $('#pic-area').outerHeight() - $('#cover').height() + ($('#pic-area').offset().top*2);
$('#cover').draggable({
    containment: [topX, topY, 0, 0]
});
```

Comment: Perhaps you need to re-read the manual: http://jqueryui.com/draggable/ or are you actually asking about re-sizeable?

Comment: Your seems to snap. Did you want this instead http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/HyB52/1/?

Comment: exactly  @j08691 but it a lil buggy sometimes when i `mousemove` after `drag` it `#cover` gets dragged. but i only wanna move it if its clicked and dragged!

Comment: Sounds more like a fringe case or bug with the draggable.

Comment: can it be solved  ? @j08691

Comment: I'm not sure because I'm not 100% sure what you're seeing when you refer to the mousemove after drag.

Comment: @j08691 in your fiddle just drag the image to extreme top and then slowly move ypur mouse down the image and you will see the image is still being dragged

Comment: yeah I see the issue. Not sure of a way to account for that other than maybe checking for a mouseout on the document.

Comment: maybe can u present an appropriate answer @j08691 ?

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#cover").draggable({

    stop: function(ev, ui) {
        var hel = ui.helper, pos = ui.position;
        //horizontal
        var h = -(hel.outerHeight() - $(hel).parent().outerHeight());
        if (pos.top >= 0) {
            hel.css({ top: 0 });
        } else if (pos.top <= h) {
            hel.css({ top: h });
        }
        // vertical
        var v = -(hel.outerWidth() - $(hel).parent().outerWidth());
        if (pos.left >= 0) {
            hel.css({ left: 0 });
        } else if (pos.left <= v) {
            hel.css({ left: v });
        }
    }
 });

});
```

Here i have solved it !
**[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/e93Z5/6/)**

**UPDATE2**

[ALTERNATIVE](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/HyB52/1/)

```
var topX = $('#pic-area').outerWidth() - $('#cover').width() + ($('#pic-area').offset().left*2);
var topY = $('#pic-area').outerHeight() - $('#cover').height() + ($('#pic-area').offset().top*2);
$('#cover').draggable({
    containment: [topX, topY, 0, 0]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include jqueryUI. Here's the cdn http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0-beta.1/jquery-ui.min.js

It's still pretty sloppy but it should solve your issue.

I updated your code to show you it works:

http://jsfiddle.net/jonigiuro/e93Z5/3/

```
#pic-area{
    overflow:hidden;
    height:800px;
    width:800px;
    border:2px solid #000;
}
```

On the left, under "External Resources", notice I added jquery UI

Comment: no thats not i want i want  `pic-area` with a fixed height and width `500x300` less that my `cover` and wanna drag that `cover` around `pic-area` @jonas Grunmann

Comment: I was showing you, you didn't include jqueryUI, not a complete solution, I thought you could figure it out on your own from there on

Comment: whatsoever thanks for that `External Resources` . but i have figured it out . u can see my updated fiddle to see what i was exactly asking for! @jonasGrunmann